# templatedir is no longer a valid param for my puppet/vagrant setup?

Tags: parameters, vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

So it looks like I can no longer use Puppets `--templatedir` as a param in my setup for Vagrant. Looks to be deprecated in Puppet 4+ but also just does not seem to want to cooperate in 3.8.2

Considering the fact that it is in deprecation, is there a proper way to pass a map to templates in my `Vagrantfile`? The below *should* work as of a year or so ago but is not longer valid, and I am looking to fix and improve upon it.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
require 'rubygems'
require 'git'


## Base modules
modules = [
  'haproxy',
  'hiera',
  'stdlib'
]


modules.each do | m |
  puts "Testing module: #{m}"

  repo = "git://github.com/ehime/puppet-#{m}.git"
  dir  = "puppet/modules/#{m}"

  if File.exist?(dir)
    if File.exist?(dir + "/.git")
      puts "Loading puppet module #{m} from #{dir}\n"
      Git.open(dir).pull
    else
      puts "Module #{m} does not have a GIT repository, bypassing"
    end
  else
    puts "Fetch puppet module #{m} from #{repo}\n"
    Git.clone(repo, dir)
  end
end



Vagrant::Config.run do | config |

  config.vm.box       = 'puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-puppet' ## name
  config.vm.box_url   = 'puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-puppet' ## can be a hardened ami etc if needed


  config.vm.share_folder('templates', '/tmp/vagrant-puppet/templates', 'puppet/templates')
  config.vm.share_folder('modules',   '/etc/puppet/modules',           'puppet/modules')


  config.vm.define :master do | master |
    master.vm.host_name = 'master.io'

    master.vm.provision :puppet, :options => [ '--templatedir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/templates' ] do | puppet |

      puppet.hiera_config_path  = "generic/hiera.yaml"

      puppet.manifests_path     = "puppet/manifests"
      puppet.manifest_file      = 'master.pp'

      puppet.module_path        = "puppet/modules"

      puppet.facter = {
        "vagrant" => "1",
        "server" => "master.io",
      }

    end

    master.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'yum clean all; yum makecache; yum update' ## generic cleanupuppet...

  end

  # Puppet client, configured from Puppet master
  # Puppet needs to run twice
  # First run needs to install build and its dependencies, so the plugins work next invocations
  config.vm.define :client, :options => [ '--templatedir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/templates' ]  do | client |

    client.vm.host_name = 'client.io'

    client.vm.provision :puppet do | puppet |

      puppet.manifests_path     = "puppet/manifests"
      puppet.manifest_file      = 'client.pp'

    end
  end
end
```

The above errors out with

```
==> master: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> master: Running Puppet with master.pp...
==> master: Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --templatedir
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
```

went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module - my_templates and add your templates in the templates folder of the module. Then you can use template function (https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.8.latest/function.html#template) Even though template function can load a template from absolute location of the file as well, its better to create a module and then add templates to it.